# Chrome extension error background.js:3 (anonymous function)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I don't know where came wrong. The chrome extension keep on showing error

manifest.json

```
{
"name": "CatExtension",
"description": "Coding train practice-communication between background script and content script",
"version": "1.0",
"manifest_version": 3,
"action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_icon": {
        "16": "/images/cat.png"
    }
},
"background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
},
"content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": [
            "<all_urls>"
        ],
        "js": [
            "content.js"
        ]
    }
]
```

}

background,js

```
chrome.action.onClicked.addListener(buttonClicked);

function buttonClicked(tab) {
    console.log(tab);
}
```

It shows error
[image]

Where is the error?

Comment: `chrome.action` is undefined

Comment: what does it mean? How it is define `chrome.action`

Comment: I have add "action" in manifest.json

Comment: From what I remember, some changes to the manifest require a complete uninstall/install of the extension instead of just a refresh. Have you tried that ?

Comment: Your code doesn't show me any errors.

Comment: It's an old error. The UI is bad, it doesn't clear errors from the past runs automatically. Click the `clear all` button.